# Jmeter is returning inconsistent results

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

Im trying to test the performance of my system when using referenced data and when the data is not referenced using apache jmeter. I wrote 2 test scripts one to query for referenced data and the other for non-referenced data. The issue i have is that jmeter is returning for me inconsistent results. At times it shows that it took a longer response time(elapsed column) for the referenced data and then at times it shows that the non- referenced data took longer. Is there a better way i can perform this test using jmeter inorder to get accurate and consistent results. Im running my jmeter in non-gui mode.

i have tried writing the samples in one test script , but then the results in this case are dependent on which request gets executed first. the ones that execute first take longer and then the others a shorter time. I tried switching them up and thats when i realized that was happening.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is supposed to "return" consistent results. What it does is sending requests, waiting for the response and recording the time taken (plus few more collected and calculated [metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html))

I can only think of one possible reason for the "inconsistency" - you're trying to produce more load than JMeter can conduct. By default JMeter comes with [1 GB of Java Heap Space](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.6.3/bin/jmeter.bat#L151) and if your test hits that limit JMeter will be sending requests slower due to excessive [garbage collection](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html).

So make sure to:

- follow recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling) article
- monitor your load generator health in terms of CPU, RAM, Network and disk usage
- if it turns out that one machine cannot produce the required load you will need to switch to [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

If you're absolutely sure that your test and JMeter configurations are correct and there is no lack of resources it means that the system under test returns "inconsistent" results, in this case you will need to find the reason and fix it on the system under test side

Comment: im running a very simple test with only one user, rampup 1 and executing only once.

Comment: I don't think it's a valid test case, for example see https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbso8.gif response time fluctuates between 100 and 500 milliseconds for the same URL, there are too many factors which can have impact. JMeter is a **load testing tool** which means that you need to [gradually increase the load](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period) and leave the test running for some time and then analyze [metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) like average response times, percentiles, throughput, etc. In this case you should get "consistent" results

Comment: ooh , so using just one user does not really get me accurate results. I did not know that. I thought jmeter is meant to return for me the response time of each request i make. Thanks let me try running it with an increasing load.